# Help with simple 2D Lens Flare effect

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, trigonometry, special-effects

I'm currently trying to do a Lens Flare effect in a 2D game (Unity 3D) and i'm having problems with element positioning.

[image: Composition in hierarchy]

This are my elements in hierarchy. "Camera Container" it's a GameObject, contains the camera and other objects. "Camera Container" moves following the main character (The character it's outside this container).
I've attached my sun composition (Sun_Objects contains the Sun itself) to this "Camera Container" to move it with the camera. The childs of Sun_Object are the reflexes of the sun.

Then i've this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LensEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Dependencies")]
    public Transform        player;
    public Transform        camera;
    public Transform        cameraCenter;

    // Lens
    private List <LenRay>   _lens;
    private int             _lensCount;

    // Internal use
    private Transform       _transform;
    private bool            _active;

    private Vector2         _center         = Vector2.zero;
    private Vector2         _gameResolution = new Vector2(160, 180);

    private Camera          _mainCamera;

    // Accesible instance
    private static LensEffect _instance;

    public void Awake ()
    {
        _instance = this;

        _transform = transform;

        _mainCamera = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();

        _lens = new List<LenRay>();
        _lensCount = transform.childCount;

        _active = false;
    }

    public void Start ()
    {
        LenRay lenRay;
        Transform lenRayTrans;
        int randomDistance;
        float randomScale;

        for(int i = 0; i < _lensCount; i++)
        {
            lenRayTrans = _transform.GetChild(i);

            randomDistance = Random.Range(-5, 8);
            randomScale    = Random.Range(0.2f, 1.0f);

            lenRay = new LenRay(lenRayTrans, lenRayTrans.localPosition, randomDistance, randomScale);
            _lens.Add( lenRay );
        }
    }

    public void Update ()
    {
        if (!_active) return;

        Vector3 tmpMyPosition = _mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(_transform.position);
        Vector3 tmpCenterPos  = _mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(_center);

        //Debug.Log("Center: " + tmpCenterPos);
        float dx = _transform.localPosition.x - tmpCenterPos.x;
        float dy = _transform.localPosition.y - tmpCenterPos.y;

        float a = Mathf.Atan2(dy, dx);
        float d = Mathf.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        float sx = _center.x + (Mathf.Cos(a) * -_gameResolution.x);
        float sy = _center.y + (Mathf.Sin(a) * -_gameResolution.x);

        float ex = _center.x + (Mathf.Cos(a) * _gameResolution.x);
        float ey = _center.y + (Mathf.Sin(a) * _gameResolution.x);

        for(int i = 0; i < _lensCount; i++)
        {
            float posx = _center.x + (Mathf.Cos(a) * 1 * d);
            float posy = _center.y + (Mathf.Sin(a) * 1 * d);

            _lens[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(posx, posy);
        }
    }

    public void Show ()
    {
        _active = true;
    }

    public void Hide ()
    {
        _active = false;
        //ResetPositions();
    }

    public bool Active {
        get { return _active; }
    }

    public static LensEffect Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    /**
     * Len Ray Class
     */
    public class LenRay
    {
        private Transform _transform;
        private Vector3 _startPosition;
        private int _distance;
        private float _scale;

        public LenRay(Transform transform, Vector3 position, int dist, float scale)
        {
            _transform = transform;
            _startPosition = position;
            _distance = dist;
            _scale = scale;
        }

        public Transform transform {
            get { return _transform; }
        }

        public Vector3 position {
            get { return _startPosition; }
            set { _startPosition = value; }
        }

        public int distance {
            get { return _distance; }
            set { _distance = value; }
        }

        public float scale {
            get { return _scale; }
            set { _scale = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

But my Sun and reflexes are in the same place all the time.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For clarification, why does the LensFlare component not fit your needs?

Comment: It isn't what i looking for. We have a 16 bit styled game. We want to do something accordingly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Even with a custom Flare? The LensFlare component defines the main behavior, like which object to flare from, while the Flare set to the LensFlare defines the textures and their positions, zoom, fade, etc. I would think even with a 16 bit style, that a Flare with appropriate textures, and a LensFlare component would be sufficient to achieve your goals. What part didn't suit your needs? Maybe we can help if we knew what you didn't like about what already comes with Unity.

Comment: I didn't know that the LensFlare component had such options. 
I tried to create a light in the scene and added a LensFlare component with an "Outer Space Flare" and i'm not seeing anything. I think it's has to be something releated to depths, but maybe i'm guessing wrong. 
Thanks for guide me